# Why is math.ceil producing a different answer for (x) and int(x)?

Tags: python, math

I'm new to programming. I was trying to clean up my code for a class problem and I thought maybe identifying type with "int" on all my values was superfluous. Then I saw that the math.ceil function was working differently with out the designation. Is there "why" to this / am I using it correctly?

```py
>>> math.ceil(12.6)
13
>>> math.ceil(int(12.6))
12
```

Comment: `int(12.6)` is evaluated first, which evaluates to `12`. So then the outside call becomes: `math.ceil(12)`, which is `12`.

Comment: Oh, duh  ‍♀️ I’ve got to get used to how python deals w numbers, its a total mind bender sometimes

Answer (score 1):

This is because calling int() on a floating point number strips all the decimals. And ceil of a number without decimals is always the number itself:

`math.ceil(int(12.6)) -> math.ceil(12) -> 12`